# Deploying NetBeans JAXWS on CloudBees

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, cloudbees

I have created a `JAXWS` in `NetBeans` and it works fine on a local Glassfish server.
I need to deploy this on `CloudBees`. I used `ClickStart` and `uploaded the WAR file which NetBeans had created`. However, this doesn't seem to work as I get the same default "Your Glassfish server is running" page. I can't seem to follow the instructions given there, nor can I find any good tutorial.  
Can someone please outline the procedure or provide links to a tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please verify that you inserted in `$WAR_HOME/WEB-INF` a file `glassfish-web.xml` (next to `web.xml`) with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  ...
</glassfish-web-app>
```

If you forgot this `glassfish-web.xml`, your application is probably deployed under the `/app` context.

Al the details should be available on our documentation page https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish3.

If something is missing or is not clear, please tell us.

Cyrille